# Only show rows that only contain [a-z0-9]

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a varchar column that should only contain letters and numbers and no other character, e.g. ; : , @ etc

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
select * from table
where field NOT LIKE '[a-z0-9]'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are actually after is a `LIKE` with a not in the pattern:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('abc123'),('123'),('O''hare'),(' : , @'))V(field)
WHERE field LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]%';
```

Comment: Forgot the `not` I guess

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @GeorgeMenoutis? This specifically doesn't have a `NOT`, it has a not (`^`) in the pattern; as the answer states. Using a `NOT LIKE` would return rows where they only contain alphanumerical characters, but the OP is after the opposite.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you return the rows that do not satisfy `should only contain letters and numbers and no other character` and thus must be excluded. got it.

Comment: Yes, the OP is after rows which break the rules, @GeorgeMenoutis . That can be inferred from their own attempt, though they don't explicitly state it. There were, previously, comments under the answer that discussed it too.